# How to display every remaining element in List using ForEach

Tags: c#, linq, console-application

```
        var users = new List<Models.User>();

        users.Add(new Models.User { Name = "Name1", Password = "Password1" });
        users.Add(new Models.User { Name = "Name2", Password = "Password2" });
        users.Add(new Models.User { Name = "Name3", Password = "Password3" });
```

How can I display the Name and Passwords to the console using LINQ ForEach

I tried `users.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);` but it only displays the Name

Comment: `users.ForEach( u => Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", u.Name, u.Password) )`

Comment: `but it only displays the Name` Please share `User`'s `ToString` method.